# How to get MAC address of client machine in c# and vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

How to get MAC address of client machine in c# and vb.net

Comment: @Mitch: Overusing LMGTFY ? :)

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure the answer is web app which I think renders the two answers so far useless to you.

Comment: did you figured that out? if yes please share how you get the client's mac address, I need to do the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *client machine*, because you can only get the MAC address of a NIC of the machine your application executes under.

For this you could use [ManagementClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx):

C#:

```
using (var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
{
    foreach(ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mo["MacAddress"].ToString());
    }
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Using mc As New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    For Each mo As ManagementObject In mc.GetInstances()
        Console.WriteLine(mo("MacAddress").ToString())
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Had to check for CBool(mo("ipEnabled")) before getting the IP address because I was getting a null exception. I have about 10 mo's that are not ipEnabled and do not have a mac address. Adding the condition only gets the ones with a mac address.

Answer (score 6):

the desired answer is

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if (!(bool)objMO["ipEnabled"])
            continue;

        Console.WriteLine((string)objMO["MACAddress"]);
    }
```

Comment: Tested it and gave me server machine.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in vb - i am sure c# is close to this
Import the following namespace.

```
Imports System.Management
```

Declare following object variables.

```
Dim objMOS As ManagementObjectSearcher

Dim objMOC As Management.ManagementObjectCollection

Dim objMO As Management.ManagementObject
```

Execute the query.

```
objMOS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter")

objMOC = objMOS.Get

Get MAC address from the query result.

For Each objMO In objMOC

MessageBox.Show(objMO("MACAddress"))

Next
```

Dispose object variables.

```
objMOS.Dispose()

objMOS = Nothing

objMO.Dispose()

objMO = Nothing
```

Comment: `Dim objObject As Object` aaaaargh, hungarian notation makes baby jesus cry