# How to get MAC address in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, mac-address

I have developed a web application .e `Learning Management System`. In this application i want when a user login to this application his/her `MAC Address(machine identity from which user logged in)` get retrieved by the application.
How could i do this in this application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018982/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756179/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-that-browse-web-site-by-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/709517/How-to-get-clients-MAC-Address-in-Asp-Net

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783954/c-sharp-get-computers-mac-address-offline

Comment: Except on very simple, small, trivial networks, you will not have access to this information, nor should you need it. Are you working on a simple, small, trivial network?