# how to get the Mac Address of client machine in c# MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I have tried to get the Mac Address of local/client's machine but I am getting Mac address same in any of the device or computer. I have using th below code.

```
string macAddresses=null;
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
   if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
   {
       macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
       break;
    }
 }
```

Also, I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018982/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-machine-in-c-sharp-and-vb-net) but I don't know how to add the reference of `ManagementClass`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot get the Mac Address of a client machine, only of the machine the code runs in

Comment: To use `ManagementClass` just add a reference to `System.Management`

Comment: I want to identify the device. is there any way that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to uniquely identity a client machine. The best you can do is add a cookie to the client with some sort of unique identifier. This is what Google and other ad and marketing companies do to try to track a user. However, any cookie set in a browser will not be available to an Android app to consume, so you'll still have no way to link the two. The only foolproof approach to uniquely identifying a user across multiple platforms is with an account. By the user signing at your website, then signing in on your Android app, you'll know it was the same user. Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: Chris, can you please explain the this line?
The best you can do is add a cookie to the client with some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: What part are you having issues with?

Comment: The best you can do is add a cookie to the client with some sort of unique identifier.

Comment: The first time I will call the API from Mobile Browser and second time from the Mobile Application.

Comment: Which means that won't work for your scenario. What Google Analytics does, for instance, is set a cookie on the client (the web browser) with a unique identifier. That cookie, then, is available to the GA script on any other website using GA the user goes to. In that way Google can track where the user has been. However, the cookie is specific to the web browser session, and importantly would not be available to an Android app. The only way you can track the same user through both your site and Android app is via login.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get MAC address of client machine unless the client and server are both on the same LAN.